# Drive failure-Novell Netware

Tags: novell

Small business in San Clemente, CA. 2 out of 3 drives have failed.  Data is on server, can't get to server. Has to be restored to a Netware server.  Anyone have suggestions who works with Novell Netware?  Any suggestions, ideas, and help are welcomed.

Comment: Call a consultant in your area. Google is your friend here.

Comment: Hire a consultant

Answer (score 3):

Netware's been dead for years really, though there's a lot of old-timers like myself who fondly remember it. You may find some disk recovery companies about that will give it a go, best just google in your local area for 'data recovery' and call them up.

That said I'd be paying more attention to your backups (you make and test them right?) as even if you can find a data recovery company who will try to help they could be weeks getting your data back.

Come back to us if you have further questions, good luck.

Comment: Yes daily backups-no not recently tested. I will google your suggestion-thank you so much!

Comment: I wish you well but please get someone in to help you to never be in this position again, we can do that you know, we're all kind of smart but it will cost you ok.

Comment: Googled- /consultant on their way. - Thanks to all of you for your suggestions - obviously not my area of expertise!